# Fatal error in PHP: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded

Tags: php, mysql

My data not is not fetched from the database. I dont know why.

```
mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("managment");

$q=mysql_query("select name,father_name,dob,qualification,identity_type,identity_no,gender,email,address1,city,state,country,phone_no,mobile_no,emergency_no,relation,address from employee");

echo <table border='1'>
    <tr>
        <th>NAME</th>
        <th>Fathet Name</th>
        <th>Dob</th>
        <th>Qualification</th>
        <th>Identity Type</th>
        <th>Identity No</th>
        <th>Gender</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>address</th>
        <th>City</th>
        <th>State</th>
        <th>COUNTRY</th>
        <th>Phone</th>
        <th>Mobile</th>
        <th>Emergency No</th>
        <th>Relation</th>
        <th>Address</th>";

while($row=mysql_fetch_array($q));
{
    echo "<tr>
            <td>$row[name]</td>
            <td>$row[father_name]</td>
            <td>$row[dob]</td>
            <td>$row[qualification]</td>
            <td>$row[identity_type]</td>
            <td>$row[identity_no]</td>
            <td>$row[gender]</td>
            <td>$row[email]</td>
            <td>$row[address1]</td>
            <td>$row[city]</td>
            <td>$row[state]</td>
            <td>$row[country]</td>
            <td>$row[phone_no]</td>
            <td>$row[mobile_no]</td>
            <td>$row[emergency_no]</td>
            <td>$row[relation]</td>
            <td>$row[address]</td>
            </tr><br>";
}

echo "</table>";
```

Comment: Remove the `;` immediately after `while()`. And please stop writing new code with the ancient mysql_* functions. They are no longer maintained and community has begun the [deprecation process](http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799). Instead you should learn about prepared statements and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you care to learn, [here is a quite good PDO-related tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

Comment: Use "SELECT *". It is much easier and it won't slow your server down to a point where you will notice

Comment: and sometimes it is faster...

Comment: It's impossible to say whether using `SELECT *` would be faster - there may be some huge text fields or blobs in his tables. And even if there are none right now, if they are added in later, that'd require updating all the code that used `SELECT *` rather than just specifying the columns required. For these reasons, using `SELECT *` is generally frowned upon :)

Answer (score 2):

Replace this:

```
echo 
<table border='1'>
```

With this:

```
echo "
<table border='1'>
```

And replace this:

```
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($q));
```

With this:

```
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($q))
```

Also, start using PDO or the mysqli_* functions() like DCoder already suggested. mysql_* functions are deprecated now.

Comment: 'i am insert a date and mobile number into database but not properly inserted.
as a date insert 12-04-1988 but database show only 12 and insert mobile no 8882989855 but database show 2147483647..i dont know whats the problem...what format set both in my sql database....pls help me.
date int(20) 
mobile int(20)`

Comment: Use the strtotime() function on your dates before inserting them into your database: http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php

Answer (score 0):

You should set User and Password ( assuming you have one )
and if the error your encoutring is that one you mentioned, 
try this line of code before the query :

```
void set_time_limit ( int $seconds )
```

In general, and Jeroen's answer will probably solve your problem.

Comment: and/or using `limit` in the query.

Comment: 'i am insert a date and mobile number into database but not properly inserted.
as a date insert 12-04-1988 but database show only 12 and insert mobile no 8882989855 but database show 2147483647..i dont know whats the problem...what format set both in my sql database....pls help me.
date int(20) 
mobile int(20)`

Comment: set date as date, there's an option of date.

Comment: Publish a question with your code and your problem, someone will answer it, i guarantuee.

Answer (score 0):

You could extend the maximum execution time like this :

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 600); //600 seconds = 10 minutes
```

Answer (score 0):

you also need to wrap the variables in {} and quote the keys

"$row[name]" Should be "{$row['name']}"

```
echo "<tr>
        <td>{$row['name']}</td>
        <td>{$row['father_name']}</td>
        <td>{$row['dob']}</td>
        <td>{$row['qualification']}</td>
        <td>{$row['identity_type']}</td>
        <td>{$row['identity_no']}</td>
        <td>{$row['gender']}</td>
        <td>{$row['email']}</td>
        <td>{$row['address1']}</td>
        <td>{$row['city']}</td>
        <td>{$row['state']}</td>
        <td>{$row['country']}</td>
        <td>{$row['phone_no']}</td>
        <td>{$row['mobile_no']}</td>
        <td>{$row['emergency_no']}</td>
        <td>{$row['relation']}</td>
        <td>{$row['address']}</td>
        </tr><br>";
```